# Why does my app give a blank page in production?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router-dom

So I'm creating this multi page react app using react-router-dom.

```
const routing = (
   <Router>
       <>
           <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/' component={App}></Route>
               <Route path='/orders' component={Orders}></Route>
               <Route path='/inquiries/:id' component={Inquiries}></Route>
               <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
           </Switch>
       </>
   </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see there is a page called 'inquiries'. Which has parameter of 'id'. Which forms the route URL/inquiries/:id .

The route works fine in development environment; But in Production (heroku) it gives me a white page with no console errors. What is this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

in will do the same think as this:
<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'/'} component={App}>
keep at mond that the homepage should have the link to your website like:

```
"homepage": "https://someone.github.io/theName/",
```

remember this example of the homepage is use at github but it should looks likeit

Comment: Then if I replace the homepage with "." to "https://someone.github.io/theName/" it should work.

Comment: do homepage : "." isn't a good idea, the recommended way is to  put there the URL of the site
In some cases, this will work but this is your main problem and why you have a blank page.

"The homepage property is used to specify the landing page for the"

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by removing the

```
"homepage": ".",
```

in package.json file. Thought it had something to do with it.